# How to get AddThis to show image thumbnails on Facebook and Pinterest share

Tags: opencart, addthis

I can't get my AddThis plugin to show images when using the sharing button. I have tried analysing when the Facebook developer debugger, but without success.

Here is a link to the site that I'm working on:

http://mollyshome.dk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=160#.UsqihfTuJsH

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: Please, try to describe Your problem a little bit more in depth. From the question alone it is hard to say what are You asking. Maybe provide us with some code that are You implementing and have problems with. Users here tend not to visit links from outside of trusted domains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue I notice is that your og tags are not located in the  section of your page.  According to the FB debugger:

The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

This means that FB cannot determine what image you want to share.  You probably need to figure out how to get OpenCart to properly insert the og tags in the appropriate section.  Unfortunately, FB and Pinterest will scrape your page for og tags, so there's nothing from an AddThis point of view that can fix this for you.